# Enable Ajax Cart in Wishlist page

Tags: cart, ajax, popup

I'm writting ajax cart extension but it just worked with home page and compare page. How can i open ajax cart popup in wishlist page?

Here are my code in controller:

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
class View extends \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View{  
protected $viewHelper;
protected $_catalogSession;
protected $resultForwardFactory;
protected $resultPageFactory;
protected $_catalogProduct = null;
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View $viewHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session $catalogSession,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $catalogProduct,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Design $catalogDesign,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory,
    PageFactory $resultPageFactory) {
    $this->_catalogSession = $catalogSession;
    $this->_catalogProduct = $catalogProduct;
    $this->_catalogDesign = $catalogDesign;
    parent::__construct($context, $viewHelper, $resultForwardFactory, $resultPageFactory);

}
public function execute(){
    if ($this->getRequest()->isAjax()) {
        $categoryId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('category', false);
        $productId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $specifyOptions = $this->getRequest()->getParam('options');
        // Prepare helper and params
        $params = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
        $params->setCategoryId($categoryId);
        $params->setSpecifyOptions($specifyOptions);
        try {
            $product = $this->_initProduct();
            // $page = $this->resultPageFactory->create(false, ['isIsolated' => true]);
            $page = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
            // $page->addHandle('catalog_product_view');
            $page->addHandle('catalog_product_view_type_' . $product->getTypeId());
            
            $pageMainTitle = $page->getLayout()->getBlock('page.main.title');
            if ($pageMainTitle) {
                $pageMainTitle->setPageTitle($product->getName());
            }
           
            $settings = $this->_catalogDesign->getDesignSettings($product);
            $pageConfig = $page->getConfig();
            if ($settings->getCustomDesign()) {
                $this->_catalogDesign->applyCustomDesign($settings->getCustomDesign());
            }
            // Apply custom page layout
            if ($settings->getPageLayout()) {
                $pageConfig->setPageLayout($settings->getPageLayout());
            }
            $urlSafeSku = rawurlencode($product->getSku());
            // Load default page handles and page configurations
            if ($params && $params->getBeforeHandles()) {
                foreach ($params->getBeforeHandles() as $handle) {
                    echo $handle;die;
                    $page->addPageLayoutHandles(
                        ['id' => $product->getId(), 'sku' => $urlSafeSku, 'type' => $product->getTypeId()],
                        $handle
                    );
                }
            }
           $page->addPageLayoutHandles(
                ['id' => $product->getId(), 'sku' => $urlSafeSku, 'type' => $product->getTypeId()]
            );
            if ($params && $params->getAfterHandles()) {
                foreach ($params->getAfterHandles() as $handle) {
                    $page->addPageLayoutHandles(
                        ['id' => $product->getId(), 'sku' => $urlSafeSku, 'type' => $product->getTypeId()],
                        $handle
                    );
                }
            }
            $update = $page->getLayout()->getUpdate();
            $layoutUpdates = $settings->getLayoutUpdates();
            if ($layoutUpdates) {
                if (is_array($layoutUpdates)) {
                    foreach ($layoutUpdates as $layoutUpdate) {
                        $update->addUpdate($layoutUpdate);
                    }
                }
            }
         $controllerClass = $this->_request->getFullActionName();
            if ($controllerClass != 'catalog-product-view') {
                $pageConfig->addBodyClass('catalog-product-view');
            }
            $pageConfig->addBodyClass('product-' . $product->getUrlKey());

            // $this->viewHelper->prepareAndRender($page, $productId, $this, $params);

            // $page->getLayout()->removeOutputElement('root');

            $product = $page->getLayout()->getOutput();

            $this->getResponse()->setBody( $product );
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return false;
        }
        } else {
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

}

```
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart as CustomerCart;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
private $formKeyValidator;
private $cart;
private $resultPageFactory;
private $resolverInterface;
private $escaper;
private $urlInterface;
private $loggerInterface;
private $productRepository;
private $storeManager;
private $ajaxHelper;
private $localizedToNormalized;
private $dataObjectFactory;
private $registry;
private $relatedAdded = false;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator $formKeyValidator,
    CustomerCart $cart,
    \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface $resolverInterface,
    \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $loggerInterface,
    PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Vendor\Ajaxcart\Helper\Data $ajaxHelper,
    \Vendor\Ajaxcart\Filter\LocalizedToNormalized $localizedToNormalized,
    \Magento\Framework\DataObjectFactory $dataObjectFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->formKeyValidator = $formKeyValidator;
    $this->cart = $cart;
    $this->resolverInterface = $resolverInterface;
    $this->escaper = $escaper;
    $this->urlInterface = $context->getUrl();
    $this->loggerInterface = $loggerInterface;
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->ajaxHelper = $ajaxHelper;
    $this->localizedToNormalized = $localizedToNormalized;
    $this->dataObjectFactory = $dataObjectFactory;
    $this->registry = $registry;
}
protected function _goBack($backUrl = null)
{
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

    if ($backUrl || $backUrl = $this->getBackUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl())) {
        $resultRedirect->setUrl($backUrl);
    }

    return $resultRedirect;
}
public function execute()
{
    if (!$this->ajaxHelper->isEnabled()) {
        return parent::execute();
    }

    if (!$this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
        return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('/');
    }

    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    try {
        if (array_key_exists('qty', $params)) {
            $filter = $this->localizedToNormalized;
            $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
        }
        $product = $this->initProduct();
        if (!$product) {
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('/');
        }
        $data = [
            'status' => true,
            'added' => false,
            'messages' => []
        ];
        $result = $this->dataObjectFactory->create()->setData($data);
        $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'vendor_ajaxcart_add_before',
            ['product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'result' => $result]
        );

        if (!$result->getData('status') && empty($messages)) {
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('/');
        }
        $this->processAddProduct($result, $product, $params);
        $this->cart->save();

        $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
        ['product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' 
      => $this->getResponse()]
        );
        $resultItem = $product->getTypeId() == 
     \Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped::TYPE_CODE ?$this- 
     >dataObjectFactory->create()->setProduct($product): $this->registry- 
       >registry('last_added_quote_item');
        return $this->returnResult($resultItem, $this->relatedAdded);
       } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addNoticeMessage(
            $this->escaper->escapeHtml($e->getMessage())
        );

        $result = [];
        $result['error'] = true;
        $result['error_info'] = $e->getMessage();
        $result['id'] = $params['id'];
        $result['url'] = $this->escaper->escapeUrl(
            $this->urlInterface->getUrl('ajaxcart/index/view', ['id' => $params['id']])
        );
        $result['view'] = true;
        // $qty = isset($params['qty']) ? $params['qty'] : 1;
        // $stockQty = $product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem()->getQty();
        if( ($product->getTypeId() == 'simple' && !$product->getData('has_options')) || isset($_POST['related_product'])){
            $result['view'] = false;
        }
        $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
        $resultJson->setData($result);
        return $resultJson;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage(
            $e,
            __('We can\'t add this item to your shopping cart right now.')
        );
        $this->loggerInterface->critical($e);

        $result = [];
        $result['error'] = true;

        $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
        $resultJson->setData($result);
        return $resultJson;
    }
}
private function initProduct()
{
    $productId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('product');
    if (!$productId) {
        $productId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    }
    if ($productId) {
        $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
        try {
            return $this->productRepository->getById($productId, false, $storeId);
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
private function returnResult($resultItem, $relatedAdded)
{
    if (!$this->cart->getQuote()->getHasError()) {
        $result = [];
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $popupBlock = $resultPage->getLayout()
            ->createBlock()
            ->setTemplate('')
            ->setItem($resultItem)
            ->setRelatedAdded($relatedAdded);
        if ($this->ajaxHelper->isShowSuggestBlock()) {
            $suggestBlock = $resultPage->getLayout()
                ->createBlock()
                ->setTemplate()
                ->setProductId($resultItem->getProductId());
            $popupAjaxBlock = $resultPage->getLayout()
                ->createBlock()
                ->setTemplate();
            $suggestBlock->setChild('ajaxcart.popup.ajax.suggest', $popupAjaxBlock);
            $popupBlock->setChild('ajaxcart.popup.suggest', $suggestBlock);
        }
        $html = $popupBlock->toHtml();
        $message = __(
            'You added %1 to your shopping cart.',
            $resultItem->getName()
        );
        $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage($message);
        $result['popup'] = $html;
        $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
        $resultJson->setData($result);
        return $resultJson;
    }
}
private function addResultMessage($message)
{
    if (isset($message['type'])) {
        switch ($message['type']) {
            case "notice":
                $this->messageManager->addNoticeMessage(
                    $this->escaper->escapeHtml($message['message'])
                );
                break;
            case "error":
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                    $this->escaper->escapeHtml($message['message'])
                );
                break;
            case "success":
                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(
                    $this->escaper->escapeHtml($message['message'])
                );
                break;
            default:
                $this->messageManager->addNoticeMessage(
                    $this->escaper->escapeHtml($message['message'])
                );
        }
    }
}
private function processAddProduct($result, $product, $params)
{
    $messages = $result->getData('messages');
    if (!empty($messages)) {
        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
            $messages[0]['message']
        );
    }
    if (!$result->getData('added')) {
        $this->cart->addProduct($product, $params);
    }
    $related = $this->getRequest()->getParam('related_product');
    $messages = $result->getData('messages');
    foreach ($messages as $message) {
        $this->addResultMessage($message);
    }
    if (!empty($related)) {
        $this->relatedAdded = true;
        $this->cart->addProductsByIds(explode(',', $related));
    }
}
}
```

My js file:

```
define([
'jquery',
'mage/translate',
'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
], function ($, $t, modal) {
    'use strict';

    $.widget('vendor.ajaxcart', {
        options: {
            processStart: null,
            processStop : null,
            bindSubmit  : true,
            countDown   : 0,
            showLoader  : true,
            minicartSelector: '[data-block="minicart"]',
            messagesSelector: '[data-placeholder="messages"]',
            productStatusSelector: '.stock.available',
            addToCartButtonSelector: '.action.tocart',
            addToCartButtonDisabledClass: 'disabled',
            addToCartButtonTextWhileAdding: '',
            addToCartButtonTextAdded: '',
            addToCartButtonTextDefault: '',
            addUrl: '',
            quickview: false,
            isProductView: false,
            isSuggestPopup: false,
            quickViewUrl: ''
        },

        productIdInputName: ["product", "product-id", "data-product-id", "data-product"],

        _create: function () {
            this._initAjaxcart();
            window.ajaxCart = this;
            $('body').on('ajaxcart:refresh', function () {
                window.ajaxCart._initAjaxcart();
            });
        },

        _initAjaxcart: function () {
            var options = this.options;
            var self = this;

            self.element.find(options.addToCartButtonSelector).off('click');
            self.element.on("click", options.addToCartButtonSelector, function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                var form = $(this).closest("button[data-role='tocart']");
                var data = '';
                if (form) {

                    var isValid = true;
                    if (options.isProductView || $('body').hasClass('open-quickview')) {
                        try {
                            isValid = $(form).valid();
                        } catch(err) {
                            isValid = true;
                        }
                    }

                    if (isValid) {
                        var oldAction = $(form).attr('action');
                        var serialize = $(form).serialize();
                        var id = self._findId(this, oldAction, form);

                        if ($.isNumeric(id)) {
                            data += 'id=' + id;
                            if (serialize == '') {
                                $(form).find('input, select').each(function () {
                                    data += "&" + $(this).attr('name') + "=" + $(this).val();
                                });
                            } else {
                                data += "&" + serialize;
                            }

                            if (options.quickview) {
                                window.parent.ajaxCart._sendAjax(options.addUrl, data, oldAction, form);
                                return false;
                            }

                            self._sendAjax(options.addUrl, data, oldAction, form);
                            return false;
                        }

                        window.location.href = oldAction;
                    }
                 } else {
                    var dataPost = $.parseJSON($(this).attr('data-post'));
                      // var dataPost = $.parseJSON($(this).attr('data-post'));

                    if (dataPost) {
                        var formKey = $("input[name='form_key']").val();
                        var oldAction = dataPost.action;
                        data += 'id=' + dataPost.data.product + '&product=' + dataPost.data.product + '&form_key=' + formKey + '&uenc=' + dataPost.data.uenc;
                        self._sendAjax(options.addUrl, data, oldAction);
                        return false;
                    } else{
                        var id = self._findId(this);
                        if (id) {
                            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                            self.quickview(options.quickViewUrl + 'id/' + id);
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        },

        _findId: function (btn, oldAction, form) {
            var self = this;
            var id = $(btn).attr('');

            if($.isNumeric(id)) {
                return id;
            }
            var item = $(btn).closest('li.product-item');
            id = $(item).find('[data-product-id]').attr('data-product-id');

            if ($.isNumeric(id)) {
                return id;
           data-product-id }

            if (oldAction) {
                var formData = oldAction.split('/');
                for (var i = 0; i < formData.length; i++) {
                    if (self.productIdInputName.indexOf(formData[i]) >= 0) {
                        if ($.isNumeric(formData[i + 1])) {
                            id = formData[i + 1];
                        }
                    }
                }
                if ($.isNumeric(id)) {
                    return id;
                }
            }
            if (form) {
                $(form).find('input').each(function () {
                    if (self.productIdInputName.indexOf($(this).attr('name')) >= 0) {
                        if ($.isNumeric($(this).val())) {
                            id = $(this).val();
                        }
                    }
                });

                if ($.isNumeric(id)) {
                    return id;
                }
            }
            var priceBox = $(btn).closest('.price-box.price-final_price');
            id = $(priceBox).attr('data-product-id');

            if ($.isNumeric(id)) {
                return id;
            }

            return false;
        },
        _sendAjax: function (addUrl, data, oldAction, form=false) {
            var options = this.options;
            var self = this;
            if(form) self.disableAddToCartButton(form);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: addUrl,
                data: data,
                showLoader: options.showLoader,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.popup) {
                        var _qsModalContent = '<div class="content-ajaxcart">quickview placeholder</div>';
                        if(!$('#modals_ajaxcart').length){
                            $(document.body).append('<div id="modals_ajaxcart" style="display:none">' + _qsModalContent + '</div>');
                        }
                       var _qsModal = $('#modals_ajaxcart .content-ajaxcart');
                        self._showPopup(_qsModal, _qsModalContent, data.popup);
                    } else if (data.error && data.view) {
                        /*show Quick View*/ 
                        if(data.error_info.search("not available") == -1){
                            if ($.fn.quickview) {
                                $.fn.quickview({url:options.quickViewUrl  + 'id/' + data['id']});
                            } else {
                                self.quickview({url:options.quickViewUrl  + 'id/' + data['id']});
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        if($('.modals-ajaxcart')){
                            $('.modals-ajaxcart').remove();
                        }
                    }
                    if(form) self.enableAddToCartButton(form);
                },
                error: function () {
                    window.location.href = oldAction;
                }
            });
        },
        _showPopup: function (_qsModal, _qsModalContent, data) {
            self = this;
            if($('.modals-quickview')){
                $('.modals-quickview').remove();
            }
            if(_qsModal.length) $('#modals_ajaxcart').html(_qsModalContent);                
            _qsModal.html(data);
            modal({
                type: 'popup',
                modalClass: 'modals-ajaxcart',
                responsive: true, 
                buttons: false,
                focus:'#modals_ajaxcart .header',
                closed: function(){
                    clearInterval(window.ajaxcart_countdown);
                }                           
            }, _qsModal);
            _qsModal.modal('openModal');
            _qsModal.trigger('contentUpdated');
            _qsModal.find('.btn-continue').on('click', function() {
                self._closePopup();
            });
            /*Show count down*/
            this._showCountdown(); 
        },
        _closePopup: function(){
            // $('.modals-ajaxcart, .modals-overlay').remove();
            // $('body').removeClass('_has-modal');
            $('.modals-ajaxcart').find('.action-close').trigger('click');
            clearInterval(window.ajaxcart_countdown);
        },
        _showCountdown: function () {
            self = this;
            var options = this.options;
            var countDown = options.countDown;
            if(countDown > 0) {
                window.ajaxcart_countdown = setInterval(function () {
                    countDown -= 1;
                    $('.content-ajaxcart span.countdown').text("(" + countDown + ")");
                    if (countDown <= 0) {
                        self._closePopup();
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
        },         
        disableAddToCartButton: function (form) {
            var addToCartButtonTextWhileAdding = this.options.addToCartButtonTextWhileAdding || $t('Adding...'),
                addToCartButton = $(form).find(this.options.addToCartButtonSelector);

            addToCartButton.addClass(this.options.addToCartButtonDisabledClass);
            addToCartButton.find('span').text(addToCartButtonTextWhileAdding);
            addToCartButton.attr('title', addToCartButtonTextWhileAdding);
        },
        enableAddToCartButton: function (form) {
            var addToCartButtonTextAdded = this.options.addToCartButtonTextAdded || $t('Added'),
                self = this,
                addToCartButton = $(form).find(this.options.addToCartButtonSelector);

            addToCartButton.find('span').text(addToCartButtonTextAdded);
            addToCartButton.attr('title', addToCartButtonTextAdded);

            setTimeout(function () {
                var addToCartButtonTextDefault = self.options.addToCartButtonTextDefault || $t('Add to Cart');
                addToCartButton.removeClass(self.options.addToCartButtonDisabledClass);
                addToCartButton.find('span').text(addToCartButtonTextDefault);
                addToCartButton.attr('title', addToCartButtonTextDefault);
            }, 1000);
        },
            quickview: function () {
            var obj = arguments[0];
            var _qsModalContent = '<div class="content-quickview">quickview placeholder</div>';
            if(!$('#modals_quickview').length){
                $(document.body).append('<div id="modals_quickview" style="display:none">' + _qsModalContent + '</div>');
            }
            var _qsModal = $('#modals_quickview .content-quickview');
            var quickajax= function(url){
                if(_qsModal.length) $('#modals_quickview').html(_qsModalContent);
                // _qsModal.trigger('contentUpdated');
                $.ajax({
                    url:url,
                    type:'POST',
                    showLoader: true,
                    cache:false,   
                    success:function(data){
                        _qsModal.html(data);
                        modal({
                            type: 'popup',
                            modalClass: 'modals-quickview',
                            responsive: true, 
                            buttons: false,
                            closed: function(){
                                $('.modals-quickview').remove();
                            }                           
                        }, _qsModal);
                        var body = $('body');
                        _qsModal.modal('openModal');
                        body.addClass('open-quickview');
                        _qsModal.trigger('contentUpdated');
                        _qsModal.on('modalclosed', function(){body.removeClass('open-quickview');});
                    }
                });
                _qsModal.on('fotorama:load', function(){
                    _qsModal.find(".product-view .product-info-main.product-shop").height(_qsModal.find(".product-img-box").height());
                });
            }
            if(obj.url){
                quickajax(obj.url)
            } else {
                $(document).on('click', obj.itemClass, function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    quickajax($(this).data('url'))
                });
            }
        }

    });
return $.vendor.ajaxcart;
```

});

Anyone can help me? Many thanks

Comment: What changes you have done on compare page phtml file?

Comment: No, i didn't change anything